# How to use TaxonomyPicker Control with Form Customizer?

Tags: spfx, spfx-extensions, form-customization

I am trying to customize form using SPFx Form Customizer solution. My form requires `TaxonomyPicker` control.

I am importing `TaxanomyPicker` and then trying to add control in render method.

```
<TaxonomyPicker allowMultipleSelections={true}
          initialValues={this.state.tags}
          termsetNameOrID="Department"
          panelTitle="Select Departments"
          label="Departments Picker"
          context={this.props.context}
          onChange={this.onMultySelectTaxPickerChange}
          isTermSetSelectable={false} />
```

In the above code, the **context** control is expecting `BaseComponentContext` but I am getting `FormCustomizerContext` from props.

How to resolve this issue?

Is there any way to convert `FormCustomizerContext` to `BaseComponentContext`?

Or how to create/get `BaseComponentContext` value?

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common problem when using the PnP React Controls in a Form Customizer Extension. To address the type mismatch, you can cast the `FormCustomizerContext` as `any`.

`context={this.props.context as any}`